# Características de NotificationsRegistrationHandler

Tags: genexus

¿Alguien sabe en donde puedo encontrar información detallada sobre las características de `NotificationsRegistrationHandler`? Me interesa saber:

- En qué momento preciso se ejecuta
- En qué momento dentro del objeto que llama a `NotificationsRegistrationHandler` tengo disponibles las variables que identifican al `Device` y que recibe `NotificationsRegistrationHandler`
- Si quiero agregar un dato más a la estructura del *device*, cómo lo puedo hacer para asegurar que cuando se ejecute `NotificationsRegistrationHandler` este dato extra se incluya en el llamado y se escriba en la tabla de `Devices`

El caso es que estoy construyendo una app y quiero incluir una identificación de usuarios a los datos del *device*; y que esta identificación de usuario se pida a través de un SDPanel cuando se ejecuta por primera vez la app y el usuario ya se encuentra registrado en la tabla de usuarios de la aplicación web.

Lo quiero hacer de la siguiente manera en un DashBoard que es mi objeto *main* de la app:

```
Event ClientStart
    Composite
        Interop.Msg('DeviceId: ' + &DeviceId.ToFormattedString())
        //Determinar si el Device ya está registrado
        &SecUserId = GetRegUser.Udp(&DeviceType, &DeviceId)
        Interop.Msg('Usuario: ' + &SecUserId.ToFormattedString())
        If &SecUserId.IsEmpty()
            Interop.Msg('DeviceId: ' + &DeviceId.ToFormattedString())
            SDLogIn.Call()
            SetRegUser.Call(&DeviceType, &DeviceId, &SecUserId)
        endif
    endcomposite
EndEvent
```

El detalle es que quiero asegurar que el evento se ejecute automáticamente por eso elegí `ClientStart`; pero parece que se ejecuta antes de `NotificationsRegistrationHandler`; entonces el `SDPanel SDLogIn` se ejecuta siempre.

Answer (score 3):

Respondiendo a tus preguntas:

1. Información detallada puedes encontrar en la documentación (en inglés): *[HowTo: Using Devices Registration Service for Push Notifications](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?18149,HowTo%3A%20Using%20Devices%20Registration%20Service%20for%20Push%20Notifications,)*
2. Se ejecuta la primera vez que el usuario utiliza la aplicación. Primero se le pide permiso al usuario para enviarle notificaciones, y si el usuario lo permite, entonces se llama al `NotificationsRegistrationHandler`. Notar que es posible que nunca se ejecute para un determinado dispositivo, si el usuario decide que no quiere recibir notificaciones de la aplicación.
3. No hay un "objeto" que llame al `NotificationsRegistrationHandler`, es el sistema que lo hace... Por lo tanto la pregunta de en qué momento están disponibles las variables, no tiene sentido.
4. No es posible agregar más información a lo que recibe el `NotificationsRegistrationHandler`, justamente porque se llama de forma interna y la firma del `Procedure` tiene que ser la que ya está definida.

De todas formas, no me queda del todo claro lo que quieres conseguir con esto... En el código de ejemplo hay una variable `&DeviceId` que no queda claro de donde sale.

¿La pregunta es cómo obtener este `&DeviceId`? Porque si es eso, se puede obtener usando [la API de `ClientInformation`](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?31271,ClientInformation%20external%20object). No es necesario usar el `NotificationsRegistrationHandler`.

Por ejemplo:

```
Event ClientStart
    composite
        &DeviceId = ClientInformation.Id
        ...
    endcomposite
EndEvent
```

Answer (score 0):

Marcos,
Mi pregunta va en el sentido de que necesito añadir una identificación de usuario al registro del device.

La variable &DeviceID es una de las que recibe NotificationsRegistrationHandler y si bien entiendo que este se llama desde el objeto en el que he habilitado las notificaciones esta variable debe estar disponible para dicho objeto; o me equivoco?

La idea que quiero implementar es agregar la ID del usuario al registro que ya escribió NotificationsRegistrationHandler.

Preguntar en que momento se ejecuta NotificationsRegistrationHandler iba en el sentido de poder determinar en que momento puedo hacer el llamado a el objeto que solicita la id del usuario para poder completar el registro. Por eso el querer saber en que momento están disponibles las variables que recibe NotificationsRegistrationHandler por que en el objeto llamador no están definidas

Todo esto es debido a que en la aplicación que quiero desarrollar los usuarios están clasificados por jerarquias y dependiendo de estas deben recibir o no ciertos mensajes; por ejemplo:
El usuario 1 recibe una notificación y no la atiende en un tiempo determinado (3 horas) entonces la notificación debe ser escalada a un usuario de nivel superior para que este la atienda. Y creo que este tipo de comportamiento lo puedo conseguir identificando que usuario tiene asociado que dispositivo.

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado mi problemas añadiendo una transacción con los atributos de identificación del cliente e identificación del Device.

Y utilizando:

```
    Event ClientStart
    Composite
       &DeviceId   = ClientInformation.Id   
       &DeviceType = ClientInformation.DeviceType
        //Determinar si el usuario y device ya están registrados
        &SecUserId = GetRegUser.Udp(&DeviceId)
        If &SecUserId.IsEmpty()
           //La combinación usuario device no existe
            SDLogIn.Call(&SecUserName)  //Solicitar datos de usuario
            SetRegUser.Call(&SecUserId, &DeviceId, &SecUserName, &DeviceType)  //Registrar la combinación usuario, device
        endif
    endcomposite
EndEvent
```